# complete diagram (repeating the code)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Working with latex `beamer` I have:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);



\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);


\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Boooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={aiiiii}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);

\end{scope}
\coordinate (O) at (0,4);


\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);


\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={boooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={aiai}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);

\end{scope}

\coordinate (O) at (-2,-2);


\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);


\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={loooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={nana}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);

\end{scope}



\end{tikzpicture}




\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works, but I want to draw two other of this shape one at left side of this shape and the other under and between if the others.

I add again similar code  but it dose not work. I know that one should change  the numbers but to what for the scope ?

Comment: Can you draw a sketch what the result should look like? And would does "it dose not work" mean?

Comment: What did you try? If you want a scope to the left of that one, you need a smaller value for `xshift`. To put something below, you need e.g. `yshift=-5cm` (or some other length).

Comment: Suppose "A" be the resulted shape of the above codes. Consider the coordinate plane of numbers.  I would like  to have one A at (0,0) another A at (0,4)   and the last A  at (2,-2). (the numbers are  just for the example.

Comment: from " dose not work" I mean the " Boooo" and "aiiiiiii"  do not take place in the right place (The right place is the place they are in " A")

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried though? It worked when I tested. (By copying the `scope` environment, and changing `xshift=6cm` to e.g. `xshift=2cm`.)

Comment: So the problem is that you have the `O` coordinate away from `(0,0)`, but the text decoration is centered on `(0,0)`. If you inside each `scope` have `\coordinate (O) at (0,0);` as Denis showed, then the circles and text are placed around the same center point, and `xshift` moves both the same amount. When you have `O` at e.g. `(4,0)`, and `xshift=2cm` in addition, the center of the circles is at `(6,0)`, while the text is centered on `(2,0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,scale=1]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Boooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={aiiiii}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,scale=1]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Boooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={aiiiii}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-4cm,scale=1]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=blue!40] (O) circle (2);
\draw[fill=pink!70] (O) circle (1.00);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={Boooo}},decorate] (0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path,reverse path,text align={align=center},text={aiiiii}},decorate] (1.3,0) arc (0:180:1.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]